# How to add python to CMD?

Tags: python, cmd

[image]

The Chinese words read 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.

I followed instructions on the Internet to solve this and did the followings. However, python is still not recognized. My computer runs windows 10 and my python version is 3.7.

I am a complete novice in programming. Your help means a lot to me. Thank you in advance.

[image]

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python3.7)

Comment: Can you run `py` from the command line? The recommended way to run Python on Windows nowadays is with [the `py` launcher](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/), which can handle things like multiple Python installations without you needing to understand how to monkey with environment variables and Explorer file associations.

Comment: Also, instead of following random "instructions on the internet", which may be out of date, it's usually better to follow the instructions on python.org.

Comment: abarnert, you are right. The links you gave me below address  my problem directly. I should always look up instructions on the official site first.

Comment: What instructions?

Comment: One solution is install `git` and run python at the git bash

Comment: @MaxvonHippel The Python docs include [Python Setup and Usage](https://docs.python.org/3/using/index.html) for each version. (For `pip` and PyPI, see the Python Packaging User Guide](https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/).)

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.3, the installer automatically installs the `py` launcher on your path, and since 3.6, it doesn't put `python` itself on your path unless you enable a checkbox in the installer.

And that's fine, because you usually want to use `py` rather than `python` anyway. See [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) in the help.

If you really need `python` on your path, the recommended solution is to just re-run the installer, select Modify, and click the checkbox. If you want to do it manually, you can, but it really isn't necessary. See [Finding the Python executable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable) in the docs for details.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not add Python to PATH 
Look for your installed Python inside C:\Program Files folder

Take note of the path of Python

```
Ex. C:\Program Files\Pyhton37
```

Adding python directory to `PATH`

Right click on `This PC`
Then click on `Properties`
At the pop up window, look for `Environment Variables`
At the first box look for PATH, double click it and press ADD. Add both `C:\Program Files\Python37` and `C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts` inside.

Now try again

Comment: You really don't need to do this. And probably don't want to, because it still won't help with things like Explorer file associations. Better to use `py` as recommended, or, if you really need a `python` command, to use the installer as intended.

Comment: Ah yes I read your answer. And it is indeed the correct way. However, I thought when he asked “how to add pyhton to cmd”, he was really asking how to add python on cmd. My bad.@abarnert